# Jackson treat field as object and include annotation in value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, jackson2

I have an interesting problem and not sure what the best way to design it. Would appreciate any inputs.

I have a bean class that needs to be converted to Json. The problem is that the field have custom property annotations.

```
@Descriptors(type="property", dbColumn="currency")
private String currency = USD; //(initializing for brevity)
```

I want Json that looks like this:

```
{
    "currency": {
        "type": "property",
        "dbColumn": "currency",
        "value": "USD"
    }
}
```

Verbose way is to create a util triad and convert annotations into fields and then use that for json. Is there any other better way to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure if I get it right :/ Is `currency` a `String` but you want it to be rendered (JSON) as an object with many attributes? I think there is a missconception here. If `currency` is an attribute of a class as `String` it could not represented as a composed object with many other data (`type`, `dbColumn`) or... are these fixed? I mean will they always be `property` and `currency`? If not currency should be a separate entity (table in db) with all attributes (columns) that it can contain.

Comment: In this case i am actually converting a legacy code. The Current code does this: class Security<T> { private static final Security sec = add(new Security<String>(String.class, "currency", "property"));  i am mapping this object into simpler object which can then be mapped to JSON. also there are around 100+ such fields in security.

Comment: In general you can write a custom Jackson Object Mapper, which inspects your Java class fields for specific annotations, read the annotation attributes and use them in the serialization process. I don't think that's a good approach. I believe you should create new layer with DTO objects, which are derived from the legacy ones and are simplified the way you want them, and use those objects in the serialization process.